# How to bind data to layout template in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, layout, data-binding

I am building a Book Store website with ASP.NET MVC 5, Razor, EntityFramework
My entities

```
Category {
    int CateID,
    string CateName
}

Book {
    int BookID,
    int BookName
}
```

My _Layout.cshtml have a sidebar (left menu), which display all of categories from database (same for all page).
I have two Controller: HomeController and BookController, all the views of these controls will
use the above layout template.
I thought about UserControl, I create a UserControl name SideBarUserControl

```
@model List<Category>
 @if (ModelCount > 0)
    {
    <ul>
        foreach (var l in Model)
        {
            <li><a href="">@l.CateName</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
    }
```

And in the Home/Index's view:

```
@Html.Partial("_SideBarUserControl")
```

But I don't know exactly where to put the binding code for it. Does it useful if I have a BaseController, which HomeController and
BookController extended from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are preforming DB calls in the `_Layout.cshtml` then I would suggest to use Ajax to get the data?

In your `_Layout` create a Ajax call to something on any controller, I would personally put it into the `HomeController.cs` but that is my own preference.

Then from the result of that call render the data in your Partial view.

This way you are not having to wait for any DB calls to finish, the downside is that the sidebar will not appear at the exact same time as your DOM loads. But you could always make it more friendly looking by using something like [Spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/)

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCategories()
{
  //Code to fetch the data for the partial
  return PartialView("_SideBarUserControl", model);
}
```

**Ajax Example**

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories","Home")',
        success: function (data) { 
        var result = data; 
        $('targetLocation').html(result);
        }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

this Way is Wrong!

ajax call in layout Makes one task occur each time the application is loaded or every time you open the page !!!

This method may work, but it works not Correct!

you nead to use viewComoponent in mvc core or partial view in mvc and cash this.

Comment: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components